# Regular expression to find <character> tags

Tags: php, regex

Help with regular expressions needed. I'm trying using regular expressions and `preg_match_all` find blocks `<character>...</character>`. Here is how my data looks like:

```
<character>
杜塞尔多夫
杜塞爾多夫
    <div class="hp">dùsàiěrduōfū<div class="hp">dkfjdkfj</div></div>
    <div class="tr"><span class="green"><i>г.</i></span> Duesseldorf (<i>Deutschland</i>)</div>
    <div class="tr"></div>
</character>

<character>
    我, 是谁
    <div class="hp">текст</div>
    <div class="tr">some text in different languages</div>
</character>
```

I tried `\<character\>.*\<\/character>` but unfortunately it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"?  Did you get no matches or the wrong matches?

Comment: Regex is a poor choice for processing XML. Use an XML parser and your task becomes trivially easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using the `preg` family of functions, your regular expression should be:

```
/\<character>(.*?)\<\/character>/s
```

The non-greedy operator `?` will prevent you from only getting one match starting from the first `<character>` and ending at the last `</character>`.The `/s` flag will allow your dot to match line breaks.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you're required at **gunpoint** to use regular expressions to do this, DOMDocument will be far more accurate.

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($data);

$character_nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('character');

// use $character_nodes...
?>
```

Comment: even at gunpoint there's no good reason to use regexes for parsing xml, but it remains possible that the data just looks like xml, but isn't quite valid xml...

Comment: @Kris, I think "not getting shot" remains a good reason to do something when at gunpoint. ;)

Comment: +1 for giving a proper answer. There are DOM parsers for HTML, too. RegEx is a great tool... for other tasks.

Comment: Anthony, I asked a similar question before. The aim of the question was loading a not-strict XML/HTML document into DOM. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473214/how-to-parse-not-strict-html-documents-indulgently

Comment: This is a knee-jerk, pat answer as far I'm concerned. Regexing through HTML can be perilous, sure, but for limited cases like Anthony's, regular expressions are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<character>(.*?)<\/character>
```

The question mark is an ungreedy qualifier, meaning it'll match a string as short as possible. Also < and > doesn't need escaping.

Comment: I just wanted to say the same, but I have lost my sample source code that was pretty easy to find. )))

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the "/u" option to correctly process UTF8 text.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php